# A method that takes any number of args, return new hash if args are key of hash, original hash if no args passed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, hashmap, arguments

The requirements:

- describe `hash_selector`

  - should accept a hash and any number of additional arguments
  - should return a new hash containing keys of the original hash that were passed in as additional arguments
  - when no additional arguments are passed return the original hash

My solution so far:

```
def hash_selector(hash, *args)

    new_hash = {}
    args.each do |arg| 
        if hash.has_key?(arg)
           new_hash[arg] = hash[arg]
        end
    end

    new_hash
end
```

It returns the `new_hash`, but I can’t figure out how to write it so it returns the original hash when no `args` are passed.

Answer (score 1):

I would just add this as the first line of the method:

```
return hash if args.empty?
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand that this may be a homework exercise but it’s a very overcomplicated and non-Rubyesque way of doing what [`Hash#slice`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Hash.html#method-i-slice) does in a single method call.

```
def hash_selector(hash, *args)
  args.any? ? hash.slice(*args) : hash
end
```

This is shorthand for:

```
def hash_selector(hash, *args)
  if args.any? 
    hash.slice(*args)
  else
    hash
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line inside the function at the beginning.

```
return hash if args.empty?
```